# Using two switches to each send current in opposite directions

Tags: switches, circuit-design, solenoid, reverse-polarity

I have two momentary switches, one to activate a solenoid and one to reset it. It is only possible to press zero or one of the two switches at the same time. Using a single battery, how can I wire the circuit so one switch triggers the solenoid (sending current one way) and the other resets it (sending current the other direction)?

Comment: NB. no one can design a correct solution unless you specify the part!  Those that try are guessing. This specifies if it is unipolar, bipolar, AC or DC, the  DCR implies draw current and will produce a large back EMF that must be snubbed with something. The switch topography is trivial but the switch rating must be sufficient. is this a commercial part?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a reversible motor driver circuit using a few transistors. In this example (from [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/211097/driving-a-dc-motor-without-diodes)), just tie the momentary switches to A and to B, respectively and replace the DC motor in the circuit with your solenoid.[image]

Comment: Do you know if this is the simplest circuit that can achieve this? That isn't awful but it is quite a bit more complicated than I had hoped for.

Comment: It depends. If your switches and components can handle the power needed to drive your servo directly, then no it is not the simplest circuit. But if you are going to have to use transistors anyway to amplify current from logic-level, then this is about as simple as it gets. Also, I forgot to mention this circuit is called an H-bridge. You might be able to get an H-bridge IC off the shelf and reduce the number of components drastically.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhEkRc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) Using changeover switches. (b) Ugly but passive.*

- Figure 1b uses two capacitors to hold both ends of L2 at ground potential.
- Pressing either switch raises that end suddenly to V+. The other capacitor will rise up to follow it but with the correct value the time delay will be sufficient to kick the solenoid over.
- R1 (and L2) allows both capacitors to discharge. This also sets the limit on how frequently the solenoid can be toggled. It might be nicer to put a resistor of twice the value on both capacitors instead. (Symmetry is usually good!)
- The switches might not last long due to arcing caused by high capacitor current. A little series resistance might be prudent.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't limit the selection to SPST switches, so the obvious solution is to use DPST switches:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMCLfO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Obviously, Bad Things™ will happen if you ever press both switches at once! Put a Polyswitch (resettable fuse) in series with your power supply to be safe.